# Запрос из двух серверов

Tags: sql-server

Как выбрать данные из двух таблиц разного сервера используя `inner join`?

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752477/joining-tables-from-different-servers)

Comment: `linked server` добавьте, и джойньте `[server-name].dbname.schema.table`

Comment: а оно потом не будет тормозит базу когда будет много даннҷх

Comment: вы опишите в полной мере что вы хотите сделать, и как часто вам это надо сделать. чтобы подключаться и сделать выборку с другого сервера вам в любом случае понадобится связанный сервер. Если выборка нужна одноразовая, то можно импортировать данные в текущую базу, для этого можно использовать мастер импорта, без добавления связи

Comment: подумайте как часто вам нужна выборка, как много в ней данных, как часто обновляются данные на удаленном сервере

Comment: У меня динамическая форма находится на другом сервере. Запрос будет использован кадый раз когда нужно будет открыть ту или иную форму

Answer (score 1):

Вообще чтобы я вам рекомендовал:

Конечно, [linked server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), с некоторыми оговорками:

- вы можете обращаться к данным связанного сервера через `[server-name].dbname.schema.table` и джоинить их.
- или сделать на стороне связанного сервера хранимую процедуру которая будет возвращать вам данные, которые вы уже в последсвтвии будете джоинить, через временную таблицу или табличную переменнуб, но выполняться такая процедура будет на на стороне связанного сервера.

И что еще важно, существует возможность создать связанный сервер с другими СУБД, такими как: Oracle, PostgreSQL и даже Excel или Access.

Подробнее:

- [EXEC AT](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/)
- [Создание связанных серверов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)